# Quicksort-How did we get the relation?

Tags: algorithms, summation, computer-science, sorting

At the proof of the theorem that the expected time of Quicksort is $O(n \log n)$, there is the following sentence:

We suppose that the partitions are equally likely, so the possibility that the sizes of the sequences $S_1$ and $S_3$ are $i-1$ and $n-i$, respectively, is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Let $T(n)$ be the expected time of Quicksort.

Taking into consideration all the possible values of $i$, we get the relation: $$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}[T(i-1)+T(n-i)]+\Theta(n)$$

Could you explain to me how we get the above relation?? How did we get the sum??

Comment: It is usually a recurrence relation derived from the divide and conquer approach relating the size of the present problem instance with the size of the smaller instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation describes *expected* runtime. Each stage of recursion creates two subproblems of size $x$ and $n-x$, where $x$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over $\{1, ..., n\}$. What we are modeling is the probability that our pivot element is the $x^{th}$ largest element. Our hypothesis is that there is an equal probability for it to be any of the $1^{st}$ through $n^{th}$ largest elements.

$$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}[T(i-1)+T(n-i)]+\Theta(n)$$

The $\Theta(n)$ term is the time associated with performing the partition around the pivot element.

Put another way, we can think of $\mathcal{T}_n$ as a random variable corresponding to the runtime of quicksort on a random permutation of the elements $\{1, ..., n\}$. Then $T(n) = \mathbf{E}[\mathcal{T}_n]$.

Comment: Can you explain further how the sum appears at the relation of $T(n)$?? I haven't understood it yet...

Comment: For a finite random variable $\mathcal{T}_n$, its expectation is defined $\mathbf{E}[\mathcal{T}_n] = \sum_{T_\alpha} P(T_\alpha) T_\alpha$. Here, instead of summing over all possible permutations, we sum over the possible locations of the pivot element. Each one is equally likely, and there are $n$ potential locations, hence the sum from $i=1$ to $n$. For each location, we get two new merge sort problems of size $i - 1$ and $n - i$, hence the summands.

Comment: I understand!! Thnak you very much!!! :-)